# Chained Installation

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

Consider a case where I have installshield software which installs a .msi through chained installation. Let's say it's Setup-1.
Now I have another setup Setup-2 which installs the same .msi through chained installation.

Now if I uninstall either of the setup (Setup-1 or Setup-2), it is uninstalling the chained msi. So the other setup cannot use it which leads to a problem. Only when both are uninstalled, it should be uninstalled. It should be something like shared components.

How to avoid this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, it is better to use the concept of prerequisites instead of chained packages.

**What is a prerequisite?**

This is a separate installation package that contains the resources required by your application to run. Your main installer will check if this is installed and install it if it is missing from the machine.

When you install Setup-2 it should see the package is already installed and skip it.

When you uninstall Setup-1 or 2 the prerequisite should not be removed. So your end-user would need to manually uninstall the prerequisite package too.

This is how must common shared components are deployed. Things like VC++ Redist, SQL Server Express, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, we do install Java/.NET 4.0 and couple of other software's as pre-requisite. In this case it is not possible because this chained installation depends upon the parent installation. The main installer will make some folder structure and install certain file which is used the chained msi. So prerequisite wont work. Second this is, each setup has its own chained msi (except few)so it will create lot of entries in add or remove programs. Telling the end user to uninstall everytime is not a reliable way for us. So we are expecting to uninstall with the parent install.

Comment: Have you considered using merge modules? Or the chained package is not built by you?

Comment: Yeah, the chained package is not built by us. We just include it in the installer.

Comment: Can't you create a search and use the results to condition the install and uninstall of the chained package.

i.e. if the chained package is install setup.2 should skip installing it and if one of the main package is still present on the machine, the uninstall of the chain package should be skipped.

I never used the chained support from InstallShield, but I suppose it had support for install and uninstall conditions

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield has a project type called Suite Installers which provides bootstrapper/chainer for installing multiple packages.  One of the features is the concept of a shared package where InstallShield will reference count the package and remove it like you want.

https://docs.revenera.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/SteSharedPackages.htm